# Не работает функция sqrt в языке С

Tags: c, ubuntu, clion

Не могу понять почему функция sqrt не работает. Заголовок math.h подключён. Интересно то, что функция работает, если её аргумент не переменная, а просто число. Например:

Так не работает:

```
double question = 45.35;
double answer = sqrt( question);
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
main.c:(.text+0x567): неопределённая ссылка на «sqrt»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

А так работает:

```
double answer = sqrt(45.35);
```

Кто-нибудь знает в чём дело?

Comment: Нужно указать библиотеку `-lm`

Comment: да, я читал об этом, но не знаю где и как это сделать

Comment: Если вы подставляете число, то компилятор оптимизирует выражение - вычисляет его во время компиляции и подставляет в код константу. Если вы подставляете переменную, компилятор не оптимизирует выражение. В код попадает вызвов функции `sqrt`, которая реализована в математической библиотеке. Добавьте в конец командной строки компилятора `-lm`, чтобы он отыскал определение `sqrt` там.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо тем, кто прокомментировал мой вопрос. Из комментариев я узнал, что нужно добавить опцию -lm в линковщике. В Code Blocks это можно сделать так:
Settings -> Compiler -> Linker Settings -> Other linker options: в этом поле написать -lm и нажать OK.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форуме JetBrains нашёл как включить опцию -lm для Clion, делюсь ссылкой https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206607085-CLion-Enabling-math-h-for-C-projects

Так выглядел мой файл CmakeList до добавления опции:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(untitled1 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(untitled1 main.c)
```

И после:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(untitled1 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(untitled1 main.c)
target_link_libraries(untitled1 m)
```

Извиняюсь за возможную избыточность, но я сам долго не понимал, куда эту опцию нужно было написать, если использовать IDE с встроенным сборщиком.